# Python 3 : When I keep a key pressed down and press then release another, pygame don't take new events

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, keypress

I have a script that make a 'character' move across a map, but when I hold a direction, then hit (press then release) another key, the 'for event in pygame.event_get()' loop don't work anymore I do have a 'pygame.key.set_repeat()' and I've tried to change the value of 'event' upon each key release but I don't know what to do. Here's the script :

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random as rdm
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#functions :

def printScreen():
    global delta
    global Map
    global player
    
    x = (w-player.w)//2
    xMap = x - player.x


    
    y = (h-player.w)//2
    yMap = player.w + y - Map.h + player.y


    fenetre.fill((0, 0, 0))
    fenetre.blit(Map.layer1, (xMap, yMap))
    fenetre.blit(player.image, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()

#variables :

h, w = 600, 700
delta = 1 #size of a pixel
run = True
moving = False

#constants :

zeros = tuple([0 for i in range(323)])
directions = ['up', 'down', 'right', 'left']

#pygame initialisation :


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((w*delta, h*delta))
pygame.key.set_repeat(40, 40)

#classes :

class player :
    def __init__(self, save) :
        File = open(save + '\savedata.txt')
        Text = File.read()
        File.close
        noLine = 1
        nbCharacters = 0
        lineStart = 0
        for i in range(len(Text)) :
            if Text[i] == '\n' :
                line = Text[lineStart:i]
                lineStart = i+1
                if noLine == 1 :
                    nickName = line
                if noLine == 2 :
                    x = int(line)
                if noLine == 3 :
                    y = int(line)
                noLine += 1
        self.image = pygame.image.load(save + '\player.png')
        self.w = self.image.get_width()
        self.h = self.image.get_height()
        self.nickName = nickName
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = 'down'

player = player("data\player\save01")

class backGround :
    def __init__(self, directory) :
        self.layer1 = pygame.image.load(directory)
        self.w = self.layer1.get_width()
        self.h = self.layer1.get_height()

Map = backGround("data"+"\\"+"town.png")

#images :

#main pygame loop :
        
while run :
    clock.tick(120)
    for event in pygame.event.get() :
        if event.type == QUIT :
            run = False

        if event.type == KEYUP :
            event = 0
            
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        arrows = keys[273 : 277]
        for i in range(4) :
            if player.direction == directions[i] and arrows[i] == 0 :
                moving = False
            

        if keys == zeros :
            moving = False
            
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] :
            player.y += player.w
            if not moving :
                player.direction = 'up'
            moving = True

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] :
            player.y -= player.w
            if not moving :
                player.direction = 'down'
            moving = True

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] :
            player.x += player.w
            if not moving :
                player.direction = 'right'
            moving = True

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] :
            player.x -= player.w
            if not moving :
                player.direction = 'left'
            moving = True

        print(player.direction, keys[273 : 277])
    printScreen()
    
pygame.quit()
```

arrows = keys[273 : 277] refers to the part of the pygame.key.get_pressed() that contain the arrow keys.

Comment: `if event.type == KEYUP : event = 0`. Why are you setting event to 0 ?

Comment: Instead of adding so many zeroes to `zerors` list and comparing that list with `keys` to check if no keys are pressed, you can simply do : `if not keys: `

Comment: Why do you get the state of the keys (`pygame.key.get_pressed()`) in the event loop rather than the application loop?

Comment: @hippozhipos for the `event = 0`, I just tried something that didn't work and did not remove it after. And thanks for the `if not keys:`, I just changed it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 if I get keys states in the main loop, the speed of the character depends only on the framerate, it makes it too fast. And if I ad a delay after each keypress, it might disturb the background/NPCs annimations which are based on the framerate set by the `clock.tick()`, but it's what I'll do if I don't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are only checking the key array if a new event occurs. You want to check the key array at every loop. You just need to adjust your indents.

Here is the updated code:

```
while run :
    clock.tick(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get() :  # check for new event
        if event.type == QUIT :
            run = False

        if event.type == KEYUP :
            event = 0
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # always check this
    arrows = keys[273 : 277]
    for i in range(4) :
        if player.direction == directions[i] and arrows[i] == 0 :
            moving = False
        
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] : print('--------------------- space')

    if keys == zeros :
        moving = False
        
    .............
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: As I said to Rabbid76, if I use this solution, the speed of the character would depend only on the framerate and if I ad a delay after each keypress, it might disturb the future animations of the background and the NPCs that depends on the framerate. I'll use this solution if there is no way to keep pygame to get events but I should have said in the post description that I already tried to unindent the whole `keys` part. But thanks for the solution anyway.